# Inject a Service into a Jasmine unit test on AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am going nuts with this, I can not get a fairly simple unit test to work (It's my first one on AngularJS).

I am keeping everything as simple as possible. I had been trying several ways to inject my service but neither of them have worked. The last one I tried is from [here](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/04/12/unit-testing-services-in-angularjs-for-fun-and-for-profit/).

This is my test file:

```
describe('product service',function(){
    var ProductService;
    beforeEach(module('inspinia'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_ProductService_) {
        ProductService = _ProductService_;
    }));
    describe('Test',function(){
        it("should be aware that true is true", function() {
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

This is my service:

```
/**
 * Product service.
 *
 * Service that manages products. Including offline mode and sync tasks.
 *
 * @param {!angular.Http} $http
 * @param {!angular.RootScope} $rootScope
 * @ngInject
 * @export
 */
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('inspinia')
        .factory('ProductService', ProductService);
    /**
     * clientUpdatesQueue
     *
     * Will hold all the offline operations on the following format:
     * {'Section':SectionEnum.SECTION, 'Operation':OperationEnum.OPERATION, 'Record':record, 'Timestamp':currentTimeStamp}
     */
    var clientUpdatesQueue = [];
    var products = [];
    /**
     * Enum for sections used by the clientUpdatesQueue array.
     */
    var SectionEnum = {
        PRODUCTS : 0
    };
    /**
     * Enum for operations used by the clientUpdatesQueue array.
     */
    var OperationEnum = {
        CREATE : 0,
        UPDATE : 1,
        DELETE : 2
    };
    /**
     * Initializes the client updates queue
     */
    (function initClientUpdatesQueue(){
        clientUpdatesQueue = angular.fromJson(localStorage.clientUpdatesQueue || "[]");
        if(localStorage.products === undefined){
            //GetAllFromServer();
        }
        clientUpdatesQueue = angular.fromJson(localStorage.clientUpdatesQueue || "[]");
    })();
    ProductService.$inject = ['$http', '$rootScope'];
    function ProductService($http, $rootScope) {
        /**
         * TODO
         * Will write a function that sends the offline operations updates to the server
         *
         * service.SendUpdates = SendUpdates;
        */
        var service = {};
        service.GetAllFromServer = GetAllFromServer;
        service.GetAll = GetAll;
        service.Get = Get;
        service.Create = Create;
        service.Update = Update;
        service.Delete = Delete;
        service.Synchronize = Synchronize;
        return service;

        /***************SYNCHRONIZATION TASKS***************
         ***************************************************/
        /**
         * Synchronize
         * Iterates through the pending updates queue and performs the corresponding call to the server
         */
        function Synchronize(){
            for (var key in clientUpdatesQueue) {
                switch(clientUpdatesQueue[key].Operation){
                    case 0:
                        CreateOnServer(clientUpdatesQueue[key].Record);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        UpdateOnServer(clientUpdatesQueue[key].Record);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        DeleteOnServer(clientUpdatesQueue[key].Record);
                        break;
                }
                clientUpdatesQueue.splice(key, 1);
            }
            updateLocalStorage();
        }
        /**
         * updateLocalStorage
         * Updates local storage with the lastest operations.
         */
        function updateLocalStorage(){
            localStorage.products = angular.toJson(products || "[]");
            localStorage.clientUpdatesQueue = angular.toJson(clientUpdatesQueue || "[]");
        }
        /**
         * GetAllFromServer
         * Gets all products matching the current session from the server and store them on the local storage.
         */
        function GetAllFromServer(){
            var session = angular.fromJson(localStorage.session);
            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: $rootScope.apiURL+'getAllClientProducts/'+session,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(response){
                if(response.ErrorMessage === null && response.Result !== null){
                    localStorage.products = angular.toJson(Object.keys(response.Result).map(function (key) {return response.Result[key]}));
                }else if(response.ErrorMessage !==null){
                    alert(response.ErrorMesage);
                }
            })
            .error(function(response){
                alert('Something went wrong. Please try again: '+response);
            });
        }
        /***************LOCAL TASKS*************************
         ***************************************************/
        /**
         * GetAll
         * Gets all the products from the local storage
         *
         * @return {Array} products
         */
        function GetAll(){
            if(localStorage.products !== undefined) {
                return angular.fromJson(localStorage.products);
            }else{
                GetAllFromServer();
            }
        }
        /**
         * Gets the specified product by its primary key
         *
         * @param {String} InvProductId
         * @return {Object} product
         */
        function Get(id){
            products = GetAll();
            var thisProduct = products.filter(function(p){
                return p.InvProductId === id;
            });
            updateLocalStorage();
            return thisProduct[0];
        }
        /**
         * Creates a product
         *
         * @param {Object} product
         */
        function Create(product){
            var result = true;
            if(!ValidateSnapshot(product)){
                return false;
            }
            products = GetAll();
            products.push(product);
            clientUpdatesQueue.push({'Section':SectionEnum.PRODUCTS, 'Operation':OperationEnum.CREATE, 'Record':product, 'Timestamp':Date.now()});
            updateLocalStorage();
            return result;
        }
        /**
         * Updates a product
         *
         * @param {Object} product
         */
        function Update(product){
            var result = true;
            if(!ValidateSnapshot(product)){
                return false;
            }
            products = GetAll();
            for (var key in products) {
                if(products[key].InvProductId === product.InvProductId){
                    products[key] = product;
                }
            }
            clientUpdatesQueue.push({'Section':SectionEnum.PRODUCTS, 'Operation':OperationEnum.UPDATE, 'Record':product, 'Timestamp':Date.now()});
            updateLocalStorage();
            return result;
        }
        /**
         * Deletes a product
         *
         * @param {Object} product
         */
        function Delete(product){
            var result = true;
            products = GetAll();
            for (var key in products) {
                if(products[key].InvProductId === product.InvProductId){
                    products.splice(key, 1);
                }
            }
            clientUpdatesQueue.push({'Section':SectionEnum.PRODUCTS, 'Operation':OperationEnum.DELETE, 'Record':product, 'Timestamp':Date.now()});
            updateLocalStorage();
            return result;
        }
        /***************SERVER COMMUNICATION****************
         ***************************************************/
        /**
         * Creates a product on the server
         *
         * @param {Object} product
         */
        function CreateOnServer(product){
            var session = angular.fromJson(localStorage.session);
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: $rootScope.apiURL+'createProduct/'+session,
                data: $.param(product),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(response){
                if(response.ErrorMessage === null && response.Result !== null){
                    mixpanel.track("Product successfuly created at server: " + response.Result.InvProductId);
                }
            })
            .error(function(data){
                mixpanel.track("Create Product Went Wrong: "+data);
                alert('Something went wrong with product creation: '+data);
            });
        }
        /**
         * Updates a product on the server
         *
         * @param {Object} product
         */
        function UpdateOnServer(product){
            var session = angular.fromJson(localStorage.session);
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: $rootScope.apiURL+'updateProduct/'+session,
                data: $.param(product),
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            }).success(function(response){
                if(response.ErrorMessage === null && response.Result !== null){
                    mixpanel.track("Product successfuly edited: " + response.Result.InvProductId);
                }
            })
            .error(function(data){
                mixpanel.track("Create Product Went Wrong: "+data);
                alert('Something went wrong with product creation: '+data);
            });
        }
        /**
         * TODO
         * Deletes a product on the server
         *
         * @param {Object} product
         */
        function DeleteOnServer(product){
            return true;
        }
        /***************VALIDATION UTILITIES****************
         ***************************************************/
        function ValidateSnapshot(product){
            var result = true;
            if(product === null || product === undefined){
                return false;
            }
            if(!product.ApplicableTaxKeys.split(',') instanceof Array || product.ApplicableTaxKeys !== null){
                return false;
            }
            if(product.Barcode.length < 1 || product.Barcode === null || product.Barcode === undefined){
                return false;
            }
            if(product.CliClientId.length !== 10){
                return false;
            }
            if(product.Description.length < 1 || product.Description === null || product.Description === undefined){
                return false;
            }
            if(product.InternalCode.length < 1 || product.InternalCode === null || product.InternalCode === undefined){
                return false;
            }
            if(!product.InvProductCategoryId.split(',') instanceof Array || product.InvProductCategoryId !== null){
                return false;
            }
            if(product.Name.length < 1 || product.Name === null || product.Name === undefined){
                return false;
            }
            if(product.SaleUnitType.length < 1 || product.SaleUnitType === null || product.SaleUnitType === undefined){
                return false;
            }
            if(product.Status.length < 1 || product.Status === null || product.Status === undefined){
                return false;
            }
            if(product.UnitMeasure.length < 1 || product.UnitMeasure === null || product.UnitMeasure === undefined){
                return false;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
})();
```

And this is the error I get when I try to run the test:

```
$ karma start
01 02 2016 22:05:54.839:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
01 02 2016 22:05:54.848:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.19 server started at http://localhost:9876/
01 02 2016 22:05:54.854:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
01 02 2016 22:05:55.101:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket /#LoDbe6y-md8uPHi-AAAA with id 31143204
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) product service Test should be aware that true is true FAILED
    /home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:4116:53
    forEach@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:323:24
    loadModules@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:4076:12
    createInjector@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/js/angular/angular.js:4002:22
    workFn@/home/eduardo/ventamia/vm2/clientside/www-app/node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2506:60
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.044 secs / 0.01 secs)
```

If I remove the lines where I try to inject my service, the test passes, so I think everything else is fine.

Karma config file:

```
 module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'angular/angular.min.js',
        '../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'app.js',
        'app-services/*.js',
        'app-services-tests/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

---

EDIT: I moved my karma conf file a directory up to discard any weird behavior to do with the ../ notation. But I am still getting the same error. I ended up with this conf file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'js/angular/angular.min.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'js/app.js',
        'js/app-services/*.js',
        'js/app-services-tests/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [
    ],
    preprocessors: {
    },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you please share karma config file

Answer (score 1):

You saying that 
    `after removing  the lines where I try to inject my service, the test passes`

because your test case not using any  `angular mocking stuff`.

They purely used `Jasmine stuff`.

Its means that your  **angular-mocks.js is not getting loaded.**

I have checked with same code and only difference is that loading of `angular-mocks.js` library.

Please check path for `angular-mocks.js` in your `karma_config file`.

After looking your base path in `Karma config`,the path for `angular-mocks.js` should be like this `angular/angular.min.js`.

If your `node_modules` is outside `angular` folder then use  this path `'../node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js'`.

EDIT : Please update this.

```
files: [
        'js/angular/angular.min.js',
        'node_modules/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
        'js/app-services/*.js',
        'js/app.js',
        'js/app-services-tests/*.js'
    ],
```

UPDATE :

well,the solution is,you should define `one main module which is your ng-app`.

Then create module for each things like Services,Controller etc and inject them in one module.

Considering these things,define one module  for `ProductService` & related services e.g. `serviceModule`.

`angular.module('serviceModule',[])`  //service.js

Inject it in main module

`var app = angular.module('inspinia',['serviceModule'])`  // app.js

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question (I already had that last path you point me).

Comment: Your js folder and karma js are at the same level in your app directory

Comment: Yes. My karma configuration file, js folder and noode_modules folder are at the same level.

Comment: Thanks. On that order (app-services before app.js), it gives me this error: "Module 'inspinia' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.". Swapping the orders (app.js before app-services) gives me the same error as before.

Comment: No,then something is wrong with your service.js module declaration

Comment: Does it have something to do that my service takes the $http and $rootScope services injected?

Comment: Thanks, I've shared my service on The que question (second script)